# Android application not showing AdMob ads

Tags: android, admob

I will soon release my first Android application on the Google store. But I have one problem. It shows test ads, but when I change my ad to real one it is not showing. I am using AdMob for ads.

I read in one place that they show 1 or 2 hours AFTER I put my app on store. But if that is not true I can get myself in problems (my app functionalities are bounded to ad showing).

Please someone who has experience tell me is this true (or solve problem different way)

Comment: If you created 1 or 2 hours ago, the ad won't show. You have to wait a bit. You can look at this for more details: https://support.google.com/admob/answer/9469204?hl=en

Comment: No, I created it almost a year ago

Answer (score 0):

Test ads are always shown on the emulator. If you are using a real device and still get no real ads after a few hours, then search the logcat for "testdevice". Usually, if the AdMob library recognises an emulator or a debug build, it lets you know that it considers this as a test device. You have to use a real device and a signed release version of your app. You can also upload your app to the PlayStore Alpha or Beta channel and test it from there if you want to be 100% sure.

Comment: yes I use real device and yes my apk is signed release version...

Comment: ok, then @Kamran answer is a good summary of checks. As he/she wrote: As soon as you see your test ads, your implementation is correct. From then on, the error has to be somewhere else, but not in your code.

Comment: second statement "Your app needs to be published on play store for showing real ads" is actually the question I asked if you look more carefully. I didn't publish it on store beacuse I am affraid that it will not work since I never red that in any serious documentation or place, but only from people comments...

Comment: I never wrote that you NEED to publish it in the playstore. What I meant was that this is another way to make sure that your device is not interpretated as a test device.

Comment: Oh OK i misunderstood. Than I have no idea how ti fix this :(

Answer (score 0):

Admob shows real ads if following conditions are met:

1. See if you have added a payment method in admob console.
2. Your app needs to be published on play store for showing real ads.
3. Check your email inbox regularly. Admob asks for personal identification once in a while to resolve it you will need to add your national id card picture.
4. Sometimes they restrict your ads due to invalid traffic checks.

If your test ads are working it means you have implemented it correctly.

Comment: are you sure about second statement "Your app needs to be published on play store for showing real ads."?  
I write in question that I didn't publish it since ads don't work and I am not sure that publishing will help. Can you please show me the place where you red this info?

Comment: I am speaking from personal experience. They have not documented it anywhere but they started doing this a while ago. What have you got to loose in trying. You can always update ;)

Comment: And there may be one more reason, no ads are available for your app. So you need to check the callback for potential errors.